# How to optimize my solution to dp programming to algorithmic task faster

Tags: algorithm, performance, optimization, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

> Now when we have a computer we need to power it, for n days. Each days shop offers m batteries which will last for only one day each. Additionaly when you are buying k items that day you need to pay tax which is k^2. Print the minimum cost to run your computer for n days

```
For example for 
5 5
100 1 1 1 1 
100 2 2 2 2 
100 3 3 3 3 
100 4 4 4 4
100 5 5 5 5 
Output will be 18
```

```
10 1 
1000000000
1000000000
1000000000
1000000000
1000000000
1000000000
1000000000
1000000000
1000000000
1000000000
Output will be 10000000010
```

I cannot approach this task faster than checking all possibilities. Can you point me to better solution. Limits 1 <= n * m <= 10^6 price can be from 1 to 10^9.

Comment: Please explain your input format.

Comment: N M after N rows with M prices for each day

Comment: And how do you arrive at the expected output from each example?

Comment: It’s obvious for the seonc case but for the first it will be 2 from the first day with price 1; one from the second with price 2; one from the third with price 3 and one with price 4 from the 4th day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply for each day sort elements (you will want to pick the lowest price first for each day) and add item to priority queue as value + tax(when tax is calculated as **2 * j -1** where j is j-th item worthed to buy that day. That's working cause k^2 - (k + 1)^2. And each day you will remove first item (best battery you can currently buy).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int n, m;
vector <long long> pom;
int x;
priority_queue<long long> q;

long long score;

int main(){
    cin.tie(0);
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);

    cin >> n >> m;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            cin >> x;
            pom.push_back(x);
        }
        sort(pom.begin(), pom.end());

        for(int j = 0; j < pom.size(); j++){
            pom[j] += 1 + 2 * j;
            q.push(-pom[j]);
        }
        pom.clear();
        score += q.top();
        q.pop();
    }

    cout << -score;


}
```

Complexity for that solution is O(n*m logm)